# Shared Project Reference not available for MVC Projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I have just upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 and I now cant add a shared project reference to a MVC project. I can add them to Console and Class Library projects and upgraded projects that use them still have the working references, but you can see to link to Shared project, using the Visual Studio 2015 UI (right click on reference).

I suppose I could manually add the reference I need in the .csproj file, but I am concerned that there is a wider reason that these project types do not seem to support shared project types.

Is there a specific reason for this omission or is it an oversight?

Comment: This seems to have been fixed now in an VS update. Must have been an oversight